# Undefined element of array javascript odoo 14

Tags: javascript, promise, console, odoo, odoo-14

I'm making an odoo14 module that makes an app filter to the menu.
In a js file, I have the following:

```
getApps: function () {
            var apps = this._filterApps(this._apps);            
            console.log(apps);            
            console.log(apps[0].appActive); 
            console.log(apps[0].menuID);            
            return apps;            
        },
```

The console output is this:

[image: Console log response]

That is: Js identify all the array elements (including the appActive index) if I make a log for the entire array. But if I want to see the specific index (appActive) by self, I can't.

The array pattern that I use in the application is the next:

```
this._apps = _.map(menuData.children, function (appMenuData) {
     return {
          actionID: parseInt(appMenuData.action.split(',')[1]),
          menuID: appMenuData.id,
          name: appMenuData.name,
          xmlID: appMenuData.xmlid,
          web_icon_data: appMenuData.web_icon_data,
          appActive: appMenuData.active,
        };
 });
```

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Please [do not post images of code or errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) - 
see the answer in the link on why images can hinder others helping you.

Comment: Please post the entire content of your console.log

Comment: Your value is not in `0` index, but it is in `apps[17].appActive`

Comment: My value is in each element of the array...The process that I execute is async...I think that is a Promise solution